# How to run a double click sub procedure over a whole workbook in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to double click any line in column 1 and open up another spreadsheet that corresponds to that line.  I have it working on one sheet, but I cannot work out how to make it work across the entire workbook.  Please help

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim fpath As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim Tname As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Tname = ActiveSheet.Name

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            i = Target.Column

            fpath = "Q:\Construction\Road\Patrols\" & Tname & "\"

            Select Case i
                Case 1: fname = ActiveCell.Value & ".xlsx"
            End Select

            If Dir(fpath & fname) = vbNullString Then
                MsgBox ("The file does not exist")
            Else
                ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink fpath & fname
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is located in the3 module of a particular worksheet.

To make it apply to the entire workbook, shift your code to the `ThisWorkbook` module, and use `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick` event

Revised code, with some optimisations

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim fPath As String

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        fPath = "Q:\Construction\Road\Patrols\" & Sh.Name & "\" & Target.Value & ".xlsx"
        If Dir(fPath) = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox ("The file does not exist")
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink fPath
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I am getting a Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name ... How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to use the declaration supplied by the `Workbook` event.  See update